# roundcube installation error. Mimetype to file extension mapping: NOT OK

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2019, roundcube

I'm trying to install Roundcube 1.4.9 on the windows server 2019 with IIS 10.0

in step 3 everything is OK except Mimetype to file extension mapping.

```
Test filetype detection
Fileinfo/mime_content_type configuration:  OK
Mimetype to file extension mapping:  NOT OK
```

I've tried to set path of mimetypes.php in conf.inc.php like this:

```
$config['mime_types'] = 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/roundcube/config/mimetypes.php';
```

and still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem was that I had to download mime.type from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types and conf.inc.php should be like this:

```
$config['mime_types'] = 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/roundcube/path/to/mime.types';
```

Comment: Have your problem solved? If it is solution please mark it. If your problem haven't solved, I found another way. Copy the mime.types file into the root Roundcube folder, and declared it in the config file.

Comment: Yes it solved. And you right. I could put mime.types anywhere in www directory. (And i have to wait 15 hours to mark it as solved) Thanks